# Bézier curves pixel by pixel

Tags: python, bezier

I have wanting to implement 2d bézier curves for a while now, and I have successfully programmed 3d engines and fractals on my fx-CG50 calculator. 
The calculator has a IL called casioplot which can either display a pixel at a time out of the calculator's VRAM, and a clearing of the whole VRAM and display.

For example:

```
from casioplot import *

setpixel(0,0,(255,0,0))
showscreen()
for i in range(0,100000):
  randomvar = 1
clearscreen()
```

This program shows a red pixel at (0,0), then waits for the loop to finish and clears the VRAM with the display. Keep in mind that `setpixel()` only updates the VRAM, not the display. I have access to the math library, but not anything else. Any way I can make a bézier curve function using these limitations?

Since I am finishing middle school, I don't have a very good understanding of calculus level mathematics, but don't think me undereducated on the topic.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Here's a description of one algorithm you could use to draw this curve: https://www.algosome.com/articles/continuous-bezier-curve-line.html

Comment: There is: as long as you have a way to get input coordinates, you can draw a [flattened curve](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#flattening), although you'll have to implement your own `drawline` in addition to the `setpixel` function you already get for free. Thankfully, there are plenty of tutorials that teach you how to write a function that draws every pixel between two points on the web already so that should be really easy to find.

Comment: Mike, I already made such an algorithm based on the works of Bresenham. I don't understand how a straight line can help with curves however.